# An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, iis-7.5

This error occured to me and i cant find the cause of it. The only changes that have happened are some database schema changes, no webconfig changes whatsoever, and i am using a custom role provider which was not changed for some good time. I'm receiving the following error page:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Source Error:

Line 55:       
Line 56:         
Line 57:         
Line 58:       
Line 59:

Source File: ...\web.config    Line: 57

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

I have read somewhere that it might be a constructor issue of my custom role provider, but so far i wasnt able to fix it, so for anyone wondering the following is the contructor:

```
    private IProviderRepository _providerRepository;

    public CustomRoleProvider() : this(new ProviderRepository()){}

    public CustomRoleProvider(IProviderRepository providerRepository)
    {
        _providerRepository = providerRepository;
    }
```

Comment: Is there an inner exception? Could the constructor of `ProviderRepository` be throwing an exception?

Comment: I don't have a constructor in it, the following is a class signature:

    public interface IProviderRepository
    {
        string[] GetUserRoles(string username);
        bool CheckLogin(string username, string password);
        bool ChangePassword(string username, string password);
        User GetUser(string username);
    }

    internal class ProviderRepository : IProviderRepository
    {
        private readonly DatabaseDataContext _dc = new DatabaseDataContext();

        public string[] GetUserRoles(string username)
        {
            ...
        }

Comment: Here: `private readonly DatabaseDataContext _dc = new DatabaseDataContext();` - I guess this crashes. There could be many reasons for that. No idea what `DatabaseDataContext` is but if it is some EF stuff attempting to connect to your database it could fail. Possible reasons: database problems, connection string problems, ... So what gives the InnerException?

Comment: I have recently changed development environments, and i was using connection string with window authentication in the new development, and the datacontext which is LINQ to SQL used the connection string with windows authentication because it was the last one that was used to generate the entities from database. So, you were right, i was looking elsewhere it seems. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that inside the `ProviderRepository` class you are instantiating a new database context in a private field:

```
internal class ProviderRepository : IProviderRepository 
{ 
    private readonly DatabaseDataContext _dc = new DatabaseDataContext(); 

    public string[] GetUserRoles(string username) { ... } 
}
```

and you have wrongly defined the connection string for it in your web.config.